# what would it need to create indestructible bubble?

Tags: science-based, physics, chemistry, materials

Not exactly indestructible, at least after flying to certain height it may pop out.

I mean something like the bubble is as hard as stone or steel but still elastic and light to float like bubble, and can be create by blowing air by single human, like in this image, which I mean human blowing is sufficient enough to create this bubble.

from:https://www.futurity.org/blowing-bubbles-1850402/

[image]

Basically the bubble won't pop even if hit by sharp object or blunt object.

May or may not be transparent.

It is not necessary to be massive, it can be as common size for common bubble blowing by single human, like example image above.

So what material or solutions need to create a bubble like I describe ?

Something like balloon or resembling balloon is out of this question.

feel free to edit the tag to be more appropriate one

Answer (score 3):

You requirements all together make the thing almost impossible to do.

While curable polymers seems a good material choice for making a bubble, and I remember as a kid to having been exposed to the ads of a [product doing exactly this](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_ball_(gioco)), it will not fly to any significant height.

[image: sample of the product]

Reason for this is that bubbles float because of the buoyancy, and they are buoyant because of the temperature difference. Since you exclude balloons, it means that the only source of heat will be the human lungs.

That gives a temperature differential of at most few tens of degrees, which paired with the small volume of the bubble means that the inner temperature of the bubble will quickly equalize with the outside environment, preventing any floating.

The bubbles one could do with the above mentioned product, in fact, would not float because of this, and would actually tend to shrink because of the contraction of the cooling air.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do this with **epoxy resins**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoxy

I was using some of this to fix the car this weekend.  You mix the resin and a hardener.  Initially the mix is gooey and I could very much imagine blowing a bubble with uncured epoxy.  A reaction between resin and hardener then occurs.  After a time it sets hard - in some cases really hard.  You can use epoxy as car body filler and it is as hard as the metal around it.  The resin can be clear.

I know art epoxy resins can be purchased at art supply stores and now I am tempted to get some and see if I can blow bubbles with it.

Comment: so.... has you tried it yet ? if you did please inform me.